# datetime field record exists but querying shows no record (DMQL)

Tags: javascript, database, rets, dmql

I am making an api call to a db which requires using `dmql` to do queries.

https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/dmql-tutorial/
I have been following this tutorial on how to query, everything works fine until I am trying to query a `datetime_field`

I am so sure the record exist because at first I used '*' as my querying field which returns EVERYTHING.  So I took the first record to do my testings.

For sure the record's field name and value is such `"L_UpdateDate": "2018-12-05T08:07:59.9",`

so for my querying I did and none of these works

```
(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59+)
(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59.9)
(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59.9+)
(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-01T00:00:00+)
```

somehow this works though but of course the result isn't what I wanted

```
(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59-)
```

not sure if any other coding I should show here since everything works fine, even if I try to use other fields to query.  Just with this `datetime` isn't working as expected.

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

PS.  I did see this post http://vendorsupport.paragonrels.com/question/4196/datetimeyyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-syntax-returns-no-results/

which suggest because url encoding which I did forget about it so I added it on which does not help either.

This is what I have done `filter: encodeURI(filter)` which would be like `filter: encodeURI('(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59%20)')` and after `encoded`, it's `filter: '(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59%20)'`

this does not work too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoded string you are showing has `%20` which is a *space*, not a *plus*.

So it does appear that you are facing the same Problem as in that big report - fix the way you encode URLs, and make sure the plus gets encoded correctly as `%2b`

Make sure to fix the encoding at the right place - at the end, not a dict - so you also don't get double encoded versions.

Comment: ah~ got it, let me see what can be done but other than that, as stated even if I give an exact value not just `+` it didn't work though `(L_UpdateDate=2018-12-05T08:07:59.9)`

Comment: The documentation does not mention support for milliseconds.

Comment: So that means, if I want to query for this specific `L_UpdateDate` which includes milliseconds, it's not possible then if this is the only field + value I have? :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MLS consider the datatime query as GMT instead where the MLS board timezone is.

Which RETS version credential you are using? RETS version 1.7.2 or older?

You should try querying with ListingID instead to test. Thereby you can conclude whats the real issue.

You also refer this page which mentions how datetime query is taken by the server.
http://sparkplatform.com/docs/rets/tutorials/photo_downloads